# Where can I find detailed steps on how to perform all ACS maneuvers?

Tags: pilot-certification, maneuver, checkride

All the maneuvers outlined in the **Airman Certification Standards** (slow flight, power on stalls, short field, etc.) have been taught by my instructor to me but on no occasion have I received reference material for each of these maneuvers. I find after long periods of not practicing these, it can sometimes become easy to interchange the order of operations of 2 steps in a given maneuver. I have my checkride scheduled and need to be able to reference these.

**Where can I find the individual steps in each required maneuver?**

**Aircraft:** PA-28-140 / Piper Cherokee

To be clear: I know that the ACS itself has bulleted items identifying required things the candidate must be able to demonstrate, but this still doesn't detail how to perform the maneuver.

Comment: The way that I did it was to spend 30 minutes on the ground with my instructor and write down the steps. I then turned them into checklists that I would follow during a flight. It would help in this question though if you mentioned what type of aircraft, some steps may be slightly different depending on aircraft.

Comment: If you are interested in what my checklists looked like, [Here is a Google Docs Link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sGhMCDYfqcvqTZgxj0x131SE-BYRWOB75dn9Raphdfc/edit?usp=sharing), the formatting is a little off because of the paper I printed on, but you get the idea. It is for a Cessna 172-P. Please note that these were developed before the new ACS, so these go to full stall or stall horn.

Comment: Thanks @RonBeyer! This is definitely useful. That being said, I would still love to know what "standard" each task is compared against. If we're judged based on performing it correctly, I'd love to know where that document exists that details out these standards we are held to.

Comment: FAA-H-8083-3B Airplane Flying Handbook covers most of the things you need to demonstrate on the Practical Test. And its free on the FAA website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question.  In the past, the preamble to the PTS showed reference material that can be used to throughout the PTS.

With the new Airman Certification Standard (ACS), those references are incorporated into each task.  For slow flight below it lists the references as FAA-H-8083-2, FAA-H-8083-3 and POH/AFM.

[image: ACS Slow Flight and Stalls] <sub>[Private Pilot Airplane ACS](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/acs/media/private_airplane_acs.pdf)</sub>

Undoubtedly, it will list the Airplane Flying Handbook as a reference.  All the maneuvers and techniques are in that book.  It is generic and the POH takes preference if there are disagreements.

[Airplane Flying Handbook (FAA-H-8083-3)](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/airplane_handbook/)

[Risk Management Handbook (FAA-H-8082-2)](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/media/risk_management_hb_change_1.pdf)